# how do I make selectable or not selectable a kendo grid by a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid, with the selection mode enabled, in the grid definition

```
selectable: true
```

I need to make the grid not selectable, by a button. I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
$("#disableKendoGrid").click(function () {
    var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.options.selectable = false;
    grid.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/585/

Just toggleClass what make table selectable :

```
$('#bouton').on('click',function(){
        $('table').toggleClass('k-selectable');   
});
```

Comment: What about making it selectable for multiple users?