# Kendo UI Listview disable selection while editing

Tags: kendo-ui, selection, kendo-listview

I would like to disable selection while the user is editing an item in an editable and selectable ListView

I've tried changing the selectable property of the Listview but it does not make any change.

See example here http://dojo.telerik.com/IvIkO

Comment: Once you've initialized the widget with `selectable: 'true'`, the element you've bound the widget to's `data` property is already populated with a `kendoSelectable`. Hence, setting `selectable` to `false` does nothing. You would need to reload the entire widget for setting false to work.

Comment: This may also be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225487/how-do-i-make-selectable-or-not-selectable-a-kendo-grid-by-a-button

Comment: see my answer for above problem

Comment: Indeed, toggling the k-selectable class of the underliying table seems the most efficient way to do it. Using this approach we do not allow selection therefore we don't need to clear any selection. I modified my previous example [http://dojo.telerik.com/iKevo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iKevo)

Comment: @Jone i have seen the above link but this solution will create problem when clicked on edit button and change the page now you will not be able to select any record...

Comment: @Devendra True! I didn't pay attention to the pager because in our application we hide all controls and panels while editing, therefore you only see the editing form and the edit and cancel buttons

Comment: then it is good for you...

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this add below given lines code after the initialization of list view in same example:-

```
$(document).on("click", ".product-view", function(e) {
    //check any row in the List view is being edit
    if (listView.items().hasClass("k-edit-item")) {
        listView.clearSelection();
    }

});
```

i have created a jsfiddle using your example and mine code, click on jsfiddle to see the working example for the same:-
http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/28/

Comment: Good solution @Devendra but I would prefer to avoid the possibility of selecting while editing to prevent any mouse click to fire the event

Comment: @Jone i have seen the link which you mentioned in your comments but that will create problem when clicked on edit button and change the page now you will not be able to select any record...